# Is there an official interface to TOrderedListEditDlg?

Tags: delphi, ide, toolsapi

In an expert, I'd like to re-use the dialog that Delphi displays to edit a project's library path and for similar purposes:

[image]

I found a [hack for using it](http://tondrej.blogspot.com/2006/06/more-subversion.html) (look for TOrderedListEditDlg on the page). As I think [the guy who wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11480/tondrej) the linked article knows what he does I don't have too much hope for a less hacky solution, but who knows... So: Do you know an official interface (most probably OTA) to TOrderedListEditDlg?

PS: I'm aware that it's probably trivial to recreate the whole dialog but I like consistency and the DRY principle.

Comment: There's a conflict between DRY and KISS on this one; Chances are the difficult to maintain hacky code you'll use to make "DRY" work far outweighs the code you'd write to roll your own. And then you'll have to re-hack every version of the IDE and repeating yourself a lot while you do that.

Comment: @Cosmin: +1 for KISS. I guess the hacky part could stay pretty stable across Delphi versions. So it should mainly be "compile and too some basic testing". But as you can see from the fact that I asked this question I'm not too keen on that, too.

Comment: You're right, I couldn't find an official way, that's the only reason I used this hack.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @TOndrej! May I ask how you judge using this hack in retrospect?

Comment: BTW, check out the `INTAEnvironmentOptionsServices` and `INTAAddInOptions` interfaces mentioned here: [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Tools_API_Changes_for_XE).
You can incorporate your configuration in Delphi's Environment Options treeview. But `TOrderedListDlg` still doesn't seem to be exposed officially.

Comment: Well, it worked for Delphi 7 and up (I assume it still works in XE), so I think it was useful. It saved me some time and effort.

Comment: @TOndrej, can you make your comment an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, I couldn't find an official way, that's the only reason I used this hack.

BTW, check out the `INTAEnvironmentOptionsServices` and `INTAAddInOptions` interfaces mentioned [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Tools_API_Changes_for_XE). You can incorporate your configuration in Delphi's Environment Options treeview. But `TOrderedListDlg` still doesn't seem to be exposed officially.